# Does a clipboard record 12 items from excel doc?

Tags: windows

In MS word/excel, the clipboard can record up to 12 keyboard items, while i tried to copy from  excel to my email body, it seems only the last item can be copied. However if i copy something from email to my MS word/excel, it can still record 12 items. How do i record 12 items in the system clipboard ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows clipboard can record only one item. Some programs (MS Office suite included) can simulate more clipboard slots for them, but it's not a global feature.

You can use clipboard manager such as [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) to extend clipboard capacity system-wide.

Comment: so the clipboard i use for collecting copies is system clipboard?and windows XP is also MS office suite?

Comment: Windows XP is an operating system and clipboard is a part of it. System clipboard can record only one snippet, but Office monitors the clipboard and records 12 last snippets for its own use.

Comment: so it means if i have total two clipbrd in my PC, one Windows, and one is Ofc, and if i try to copy anything into non-office interface, only one item can be copied, if i try to copy anything in ofc software, 12 options are available?

Comment: You always have one clipboard that contains only most recently copied item. You can have at most one snippet in the clipboard. Office monitors clipboard and keeps 12 most recent items just for use in Office. It's like a clipboard manager, but just for Office. Clipboard managers don't create additional clipboard, but monitor and control system clipboard to emulate multi-slot clipboard.